# How to cast Frohlich's Hamiltonian from phonon creation and annihilation operators to phonon position and momentum operators?

Tags: homework-and-exercises, condensed-matter, hamiltonian

I have had trouble casting Fröhlich's Hamiltonian (Eqn 2.33 in [1]) from its form in terms of phonon creation $\hat{b}^\dagger_{\mathbf{k}}$ and annihilation operators $\hat{b}_{\mathbf{k}}$ to its form in terms of the corresponding phonon position $\hat{q}_{\mathbf{k}}$ and momentum $\hat{p}_{\mathbf{k}}$. The former version looks like:

\begin{equation}
\hat{H} = \frac{\mathbf{p}_{el}^2}{2m_b} + \hbar\omega_{LO} \sum_{\mathbf{k}} \hat{b}_{\mathbf{k}}^\dagger \hat{b}_{\mathbf{k}} + \sum_{\mathbf{k}} ( V^*_{\mathbf{k}} \hat{b}_{\mathbf{k}} e^{i\mathbf{k} \cdot \mathbf{r}_{el}} + V_{\mathbf{k}} \hat{b}_{\mathbf{k}}^\dagger \, e^{-i\mathbf{k} \cdot \mathbf{r}_{el}})
\end{equation}

where $\mathbf{p}_{el}$ is the electron momentum operator, $\mathbf{r}_{el}$ is the electron position operator and $V_{\mathbf{k}}$ is the electron-phonon coupling parameter given by:

\begin{equation}
V_{\mathbf{k}} = i\frac{2 \hbar \omega_{LO}}{k} \left(\sqrt{\frac{\hbar}{2 m_b \omega_{LO}}} \frac{\alpha \pi}{V} \right)^{1/2}
\end{equation}

with $V$ the cubic unit-cell volume, $m_b$ the conduction electron band-mass, $\omega_{LO}$ the single long-wavelength longitudinal optical phonon frequency, and $\alpha$ is the "Fröhlich alpha" parameter that quantifies the strength of the electron-phonon interaction. The latter form of this Hamiltonian looks like:

\begin{equation}
    H = \frac{\mathbf{p}_{el}^2}{2m_b} + \frac{1}{2} \sum_{\mathbf{k}} \left(\hat{p}_{\mathbf{k}}^2 + \omega_{LO}^2 \hat{q}_{\mathbf{k}}^2 \right) + \hbar \omega_{LO} \left(\frac{2 \pi \alpha}{V} \sqrt{\frac{2 \hbar}{m_b \omega_{LO}}}\right)^{1/2} \sum_{\mathbf{k}} \frac{1}{k} \hat{q}_{\mathbf{k}} e^{i \mathbf{k} \cdot \mathbf{r}_{el}}.
\end{equation}

I cannot figure out how to obtain this form, which I need as a starting point to obtaining Feynman's path integral form of this Hamiltonian [2]. I haven't found the derivation to be shown anywhere and the latter Hamiltonian only ever seems to be stated as the result, implying that the derivation must be somewhat trivial although I am struggling to see it. The information I have so far are that $\hat{b}^\dagger_{\mathbf{k}} = -\hat{b}_{-\mathbf{k}}$ and:

\begin{equation}
       \hat{q}_{\mathbf{k}} = \sqrt{\frac{\hbar}{2\omega_{LO}}} \left(\hat{b}^\dagger_{\mathbf{k}} + \hat{b}_{\mathbf{k}} \right)
\end{equation}
\begin{equation}
        \hat{p}_{\mathbf{k}} = i\sqrt{\frac{\hbar \omega_{LO}}{2}} \left(\hat{b}^\dagger_{\mathbf{k}} - \hat{b}_{\mathbf{k}} \right).
\end{equation}

I run into issues primarily with the final electron-phonon interaction term in the initial Hamiltonian. I cannot seem to cast it into a form where I can obtain $\hat{q}_{\mathbf{k}} e^{i
\mathbf{k} \cdot \mathbf{r}_{el}} / k$ in the sum. I've tried things such as changing the sign of the wavevector $\mathbf{k}$ and using the above relations, but to no avail. What am I missing? How do I obtain the latter form of the Hamiltonian? Thanks.

[1] H. Fröhlich, “Electrons in lattice fields,” Advances in Physics, vol. 3, no. 11, pp. 325–361, 1954.

[2] R. P. Feynman, “Slow electrons in a polar crystal,” Phys. Rev., vol. 97, pp. 660–665, Feb 1955.